# Callback url not working while integrating Twitter with iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, twitter, mgtwitterengine

I am using mgtwitterengine to implement twitter login on my ios app. I'm having trouble logging in to my application using this library.

After giving my twitter username/password, I am redirected to the landing page of my website (on Twitter development settings, I have given a callback url to http://mywebsite.com and I am redirected to mywebsite.com after giving my username/password and signing in). How do I get it to redirect to my application's home page?

Comment: would please post the implementation code snippet? It will be easier to understand your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue before.Removing the callback url from the development settings will automatically redirect to your application's home page.Hope this helps you.

Comment: Removing callback does work for ios but if I am using the same twitter app for my android app, then android fails.

Comment: If any one has fix then please share .. @Ninja have you fix this .

Answer (score 1):

Callback URL is not going to be used by your iOS or Android app. So, it doesn't matter what you enter here, as long as it's a valid URL such as [ https://pratik.com ] or [ http://myAppName.com ]

Comment: Works like a charm for iOS. Thanks